# High battery discharge rate on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: dell, power-management, battery, 17.04, xps

I am using my Dell XPS 15 9550 with Ubuntu. The battery life with Linux is not as good as Windows. I have installed TLP and powertop, but haven't seen many improvements. Powertop says that, on idle (wifi connected, no programs opened, minimum brightness) the laptop has a battery discharge rate of 14.5 W which seems high to me. Is there anyway to improve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

It helps to disable the Nvidia gpu, there are many tutorials for this if you search for them.  I usually idle around 5 watts with the xps 9560 i7.